# Google AMP - Cache link redirect to original page

Tags: wordpress, amp-html

I'm using wordpress for the project, adding accelerated mobile pages plugin, everything is working fine, except new posts added, when opening the google cdn amp link, it redirect to the original link.

Link

```
https://www-madamasr-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/www.madamasr.com/en/2017/10/07/feature/lifestyle/video-three-stations/amp/
```

Comment: I know this is old. It's working now, so maybe you figured it out, or maybe it takes time? If you did figure it out, please share!

Comment: The main reason I came back to comment was that I noticed bad tracking code at the bottom of this page: https://www.madamasr.com/en/2017/08/17/feature/society/fatwa-on-the-go/amp/